# What would be the simplest system to send sms from linux server?

Tags: linux, sms, debian, system-administration

What would be the simplest system to send sms from linux server? It`s a Debian system. There would be not much SMSes. What hardware and software to use? Maybe use some SMS sending service?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yeah, I think the simplest way would be getting a serial GSM modem, or a GSM phone with a serial connection, and a SIM card. Some USB ones can work, but is better getting a serial one and staying on the safe side.

Serial modems don't need any drivers, you just need to connect via the serial port (/dev/tty...) and dump there the commmands...

Also, if you want it easier, you can install the SMS Tools available on Linux. They are packaged with the easy name 'smstools' in Ubuntu, Debian, and other Distros.

Last version is number 3, and you can get some info on this site:
http://smstools3.kekekasvi.com/

Comment: For phones with USB connectors, the device is /dev/ttyACM0 or /dev/ttyACM1 (you get two available interfaces), and the kernel driver is called cdc-acm (device drivers -> usb support -> usb modem). This driver is mature and has been present for many years, so the only issus is that it might not be enabled by default. Other than that there is no problems with using USB phones on linux.

Comment: You can also send SMS messages via USB modems with ModemManager, or via USB and serial with `gsm-utils`.

Answer (score 6):

If you like to to do it yourself and utilize your old mobile phone, try [this](http://www.x11.net/wiki/index.php/Setting_up_an_SMS_Gateway) recipe :-)

There is a real advantage in this approach over using some email SMS service: computer network problems don't affect local hardware. It's especially important if you use SMSes for monitoring your server.

Comment: There may be similar things built on other phones too. Try to google for "diy sms gateway".

Comment: Link provided is dead

Comment: @JohnMerlino The [archived version](http://web.archive.org/web/20130928013544/http://www.x11.net/wiki/index.php/Setting_up_an_SMS_Gateway) is not (96 captures since 22 Feb 06 to 28 Sep 13). To anyone who likes this: consider [donating](https://archive.org/donate/) to the Web Archive.

Answer (score 2):

Each cell phone company offers email addresses to send sms messages to phones. For example verizon uses something like 55512345678@vtext.com to send messages. All you need to do is find a list of each provider's email domain and then find out the service your user subscribes. After that just send the sms like a regular email. This is how most software does it.

Comment: Hm, this won't work in all countries (at least afaik not in germany).

Comment: nor in most other European countries where the caller pays, not the recipient.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are probably looking for a lithuanian service (judging from your name), look into [www.gsms.lt](https://www.gsms.lt/lit/Detalus_aprasymas/178).

Comment: We gotta Sherlock Holmes over here!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269/programmatic-sms) Question helps you. Otherwise take a look at [Kannel](http://www.kannel.org).

Comment: @kazimieras-aliulis if you are looking for some GUI for kannel then you can check this [Linux based broadcasting system](https://www.ictbroadcast.com/)

Answer (score 1):

There is another option perl independent exec. Download and Run directly.
No Moderm required. Global sms supported and free try.

you can refer http://www.sms4mail.com/smsmail/smscmd.htm

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way is to use a GPRS modem or a pool of modems. More advance - buy gateway service in cell network operator.

Answer (score 0):

Use a modem connected to a serial port. And use gnokii.