# How to send sms programmatically?

Tags: sms, sms-gateway

Are there any sites that offer the ability to send SMS for free?

How do they do it?

How am I able to send SMS programmatically?

Comment: Shouldn't this be re-opened?  I feel like it's on topic if we are talking about sending SMS messages programmatically.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Send an email to the 10 digit phone number @ Carrier's domain name.

Here is a list of the carriers and their domains:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SMS_gateways

Comment: is this a reliable way to send sms?

Comment: I doubt it. I certainly wouldn't do that for a production system.

Comment: The table is out of date (see the note). The link should be: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_carriers_providing_Email_or_Web_to_SMS

Comment: If you need a site to look up carrier names, check out http://www.freecarrierlookup.com/.  There are others if you google as well, that was just the first hit when googling "Find cell carrier by number"

Comment: @DuckPuncher, it should be noted that those websites are not always up-to-date and, in fact, they are usually obsolete for up to several years after changes such as porting a phone number to a new service provider.

Answer (score 15):

The articles listed below may be useful:
[Are there any free services for sending SMS programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269/programmatic-sms)
 
[Programmatic SMS] [3]
[Free SMS API?] [4]

**EDIT**
Removed first link that has been removed

Comment: in the free SMS API list, for some carriers there are multiple email addresses, for example: 
T-Mobile   10digitphonenumber@tmomail.net
T-Mobile  10digitphonenumber@voicestream.net

how do I distinguish them?

Comment: Exactly, should we simply send to all of them?

Comment: The first link refers to a page that's been removed from Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

I use an SMS gateway and it is fairly easy but I did consider this as an alternative because it potentially gave me more control
[email to sms](http://www.i-programmer.info/projects/38-windows/219-email-to-sms.html)

Comment: I'm using gatewayapi.com, they are good and competitive in terms of their pricing. Their API is very easy to deal with for nodejs.

Answer (score 1):

The sites that send SMS for free usually use the email interface that most of the carriers implement which allow you to send an email to (for instance) `<your 10 digit number>@mobile.att.net`

and have it received as an SMS by that phone.