# SMS / Texting solution needed for multiple countries

Tags: php, sms

I am looking for an SMS solution like the following SMS inbound and outbound.

- Each country user gets a number in their country to send messages.
- Each user will get SMS FROM a number in their country. So they can just reply with their message to that number.

EG: User in France will get SMS from the site from a French number. The user will respond to that number. The User in Mexico gets an SMS from the Mexico number etc.

All the incoming SMS (sent from the customer to any number for that country) will finally reach the website with a HTTP GET call to webserver running PHP.

Do you recommend any company that can help me out!

EDIT: **IMPORTANT TO HAVE EACH USER COUNTRY TO HAVE LOCAL NUMBER TO RESPOND**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a great provider: http://www.clickatell.com/

Here's the coverage: http://www.clickatell.com/pricing/basic_coverage.php

And some samples in PHP: http://www.clickatell.com/developers/php.php

---

Other providers: http://www.google.com/Top/Computers/Mobile_Computing/Wireless_Data/Short_Messaging_Service/

---

Similar question:
[Programmatic SMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269/programmatic-sms)

Comment: do they give incoming numbers for each country?

Answer (score 3):

There is a very good provider in the US and Canada called Ez Texting

http://www.eztexting.com