# How to hide the message content on the MFMessageComposeViewController control

Tags: iphone

I'm developing an Mobile Banking app on iPhone. This app use SMS message to send and receive data with server.
(This app of a bank)

I'm using the MFMessageComposeViewController control to send SMS to server.
The message content has been encrypted.
So, I don't want user can see the message content (I want to hide the message content on this control).

Is it possible to hide the content of message on the MFMessageComposeViewController control?

I found one app on App Store can custom the 
MFMessageComposeViewController control:

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/automatic-custom-sms/id409247779?mt=8#

How to custom this control?.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want that control. I would google for "programmatic sms". I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269/programmatic-sms)

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can hide the interface or any UI items from the MFMessageComposeViewController as it is provided to you by the iphone itself.
So,what you can do is make a similar interface and then use other methods such as using third party web solution to send mail.

Comment: But my app use the mobile number which sent SMS message for authentication. So. I can use the third party web to send SMS.