# How to organise sms-alerts to users on web-site?

Tags: php, sms

I want to send to my users sms-alert about some events on site. As the base country for operators I'll took USA. Can you recommend me any ways to send messages, free or low pay? Maybe, some classes or modules on PHP?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatic SMS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269/programmatic-sms)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [twilio](http://www.twilio.com/).