# How can I integrate SMS gateway into a website?

Tags: sms, hyperlink

if my question or explanation is not good enough please pardon me.
there is something i want to do but i am having some problem on how to start
i develop free little online game website and i want players to be verify through sms. that is, want  players to send 'start game'sms from their phone to a number link to my game website and my website game will authomatically reply with 1 to 3 question which will be answer by player before login detail will be send to a player that got the answer right, which will enable player to fully login into my game website to play my games.

i know i can this answer here that is why i ask

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatic SMS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269/programmatic-sms)

Answer (score 0):

Use an SMS Gateway service like [SumoText](http://www.sumotext.com/sms-gateway.html), they provide an API your game can use to send & receive text messages to your users. Good luck!