# Can you create a google app that sends SMS notifications for calender events to your users?

Tags: google-api, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, google-apps

Can you create a google app that sets SMS notifications for users using the calender api?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by 'google app' and I suggest you remove the irrelevant tags (google-app-engine or google-apps-script) based on what you are working with

Comment: Sorry for the irrelevant tags, The thing is that i want to create an app using google app script that will let my users book for events and get free sms alerts from the calender app. Is there a way to execute that?

Answer (score 2):

In apps-script, you can set sms-reminders programmatically using,

```
CalendarApp.createEvent('Message here',
                            new Date(new Date().getTime()+60000),
                            new Date(new Date().getTime()+60000)).addSmsReminder(0);
```

See here for a working example, https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/gmail_filter_sms

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's not possible unless you are willing to make use of another api in conjunction with the calender (I don't see why you wouldn't want to...). This may be a good place to start looking for a suitable api: [Programmatic SMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269/programmatic-sms)

Comment: The thing is that i want my users to get the priviledge of getting free sms alerts from the calender app. Is there another way to work around that, like gmail sms?

Answer (score 0):

If your questions is using Apps Script, it is possible. See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_calendarevent#addSmsReminder .