# is it possible to programmatically send an sms via a free google (or other) service?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sms

I'm running a Ruby on Rails application that I'm looking for a method to send some notifications via SMS (not many, just on critical failures).

It seems like this may be possible via google talk or google voice. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Could this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269/programmatic-sms

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com/). They might not be entirely free, but if you want to reliably send SMS on critical errors that might be worth more than a free option that might not work that reliable.

What's more, they have an excellent [**twilio-ruby**](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-ruby) gem that allows you to send SMS very nicely from any app.

Pricing with Twilio depends on the country you're sending your text to, for the U.S. it would be 1 Cent for each outbound SMS.

If you get to know any free solution let me know.

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer, I do developer evangelism part time at Nexmo.*

If you're only sending notifications to yourself, you may be able to just use an email alias for your cell number.

But if you're doing anything significant, the best solution is likely an SMS API. There are a few providers (this list isn't complete, but it's what I'd consider using) - pricing is in cents per message (depends on the API and destination, but hovers around a cent or two). You may be required to provision a virtual number depending on your country - pricing there is generally dollars/month (again, depends on API and destination, hovers around a dollar or two).

- [Nexmo](http://nexmo.com)
- [Twilio](http://twilio.com)
- [Tropo](http://tropo.com)