# Is there any api is available to send sms through internet in android

Tags: android, sms, sms-gateway, smslib

I am making an app in which i am have to send sms to another number using `internet` but i donot want to use phone native api i.e.`smsManage`r means i donot want to pay for sms to mobile operator That means. i want to use `Internet` to send messages.like `twillo` and `nexmo` but iam unable to use this api in my android app. if iam using this api in my android the application is crashing so if any api is there please suggest me. or any other references are there to send sms through `internet`. or by using `webservices`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatic SMS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269/programmatic-sms)

Answer (score 2):

The term you are looking is `SMS gateway`.. Twilio API is working well with android, or you can use some other as per your wish..

Best is [Bulk SMS](http://www.bulksms.com/). First [Register here](https://bulksms.vsms.net/register/) and then use your user name and password as shown in the example

Example:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class SendSms {

static public void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        // Construct data
        String data = "";
        data += "username=" + URLEncoder.encode("your username", "ISO-8859-1");
        data += "&password=" + URLEncoder.encode("password", "ISO-8859-1");
        data += "&message=" + URLEncoder.encode("your message", "ISO-8859-1");
        data += "&want_report=1";
        data += "&msisdn=44123123123";// relace with the number

        // Send data
        URL url = new URL("http://bulksms.vsms.net:5567/eapi/submission/send_sms/2/2.0");

        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(data);
        wr.flush();

        // Get the response
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            // Print the response output...
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        wr.close();
        rd.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: do you have any tutorial for that or sample program. for send sms through twilio in android.

Comment: you can download it from twilio itself. they give java api. you can use it

Comment: I used with java api but application crashed

Comment: i changed following link https://gist.github.com/kwhinnery/5254045.  program according to my requirement. it worked well in normal java program. but android it crashed

Comment: I've edited my answer check it

Comment: will it work with android also

Comment: Thanks. I will check. Because i registered But not got any activation code